# Disassembling VxWorks Firmware

Tags: disassembly, firmware

I am trying to disassemble the firmware for the Cisco Sx300 switch as found here: 
https://software.cisco.com/download/release.html%3Fmdfid%3D283019611%26softwareid%3D282463181%26release%3D1.2.7.76

While some documentation for other iterations of Wind River's firmware exist, I have not encountered a working set of tools for this particular firmware.

Binwalk gives some results:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Cisco VxWorks firmware header, header size: 80 bytes, number of files: 15, image size: 6988894, firmware version: "1.2.7.76"
209           0xD1            LANCOM WWAN firmware
1483          0x5CB           LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 16016448 bytes
3984149       0x3CCB15        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 859164 bytes
4153128       0x3F5F28        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2962457 bytes
4847723       0x49F86B        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2122505 bytes
6914211       0x6980A3        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 66664 bytes
6932632       0x69C898        XML document, version: "1.0"
6950635       0x6A0EEB        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 121427 bytes
```

However, extraction with the -e flag doesn't provide meaningful results. Several files are extracted, but others end up as corrupt archives, or file that are are too small to be actual files. I am not certain that the LZMA compressed data isn't false positive.

Disassembly with IDA fails, as I do not know the loader address.

This Cisco help resource suggests that there is some form of compression going on:
https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/small-business-support-documents/how-to-recover-a-reboot-loop-on-sx300/ta-p/3134953

This help support post confirms that the Firmware is ARM based, but I am not certain as to the exact make of the chip.

I am aware that previous iterations of the VxWork's Firmware had the loader address in the header. Analysis of the header did not find a useable address at the suggested location (0x14)

[image: Very likely a VxWorks Header]

I attempted to match up the strings in the firmware to string tables and was not able to find any string tables, despite a thorough search. This supports my notion that it is compressed, or otherwise packed.

Lastly, I searched through the binary for probable addresses in order to deduce the loader address. I was not able to find any commonly referenced addresses or ranges. This was especially hard, as none of the binary was able to be correctly analyzed by IDA.

Am I missing something easy and fundamental here? Is there a special technique for VxWorks firmware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This supports my notion that it is compressed, or otherwise packed.

You are correct; most of this firmware image is compressed or encrypted. In order to be disassembled the binary will have to be decompressed/decrypted.

Evidence of compression/encryption:

1. `binwalk` entropy plot
   [image: binwalk entropy plot]

   The entropy level throughout most of the file appears to appears to be close to the maximum possible.
2. Visualization via [binvis.io](http://binvis.io/#/):

   A visualization of the entropy of the firmware is on the left and a visualization of the entropy of an uncompressed file is on the right:

   [image: firmware entropy binvis.io]
   [image: bash entropy]
3. [ent](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) (A Pseudorandom Number Sequence Test Program)

   ```
   $ ent sx300_fw-12776.ros 
   Entropy = 7.999864 bits per byte.

   Optimum compression would reduce the size
   of this 6988974 byte file by 0 percent.

   Chi square distribution for 6988974 samples is 1330.86, and randomly
   would exceed this value 0.01 percent of the times.

   Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 127.3134 (127.5 = random).
   Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.145007550 (error 0.11 percent).
   Serial correlation coefficient is 0.002524 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).
   ```

   See http://www.devttys0.com/2013/06/differentiate-encryption-from-compression-using-math/